Find difference between dates with a given condition
In a dataset, I am trying to find date differences between the two types of 'ACQDISP' (say purchase and sales of shares). I am trying to find days differences between purchase (A) to purchase (A), purchase (A) to sales (D), sales (D) to sales (D) and sales (D) to purchase (A)  For an instance, I have first three rows 'D' (see ACQDISP column) in the same date (see TRANDATE). I can calculate distance between 'D' and 'D' or 'A' and 'A' with the following code.
import polars as pl

df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ ACQDISP ┆ TRANDATE   ┆ SHARES_ADJ ┆ TPRICE_ADJ │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str     ┆ str        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞═════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 2000.0     ┆ 6.7        │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 6000.0     ┆ 6.45       │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 3000.0     ┆ 6.52       │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-09 ┆ 5.4e6      ┆ 60.75      │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 2.1954e6   ┆ null       │
│ D       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 4.63418e6  ┆ 52.435     │
│ A       ┆ 2014-12-17 ┆ 3.84581e6  ┆ null       │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
""")

df = df.with_columns(TRANDATE=pl.col("TRANDATE").str.to_date())  
df = df.sort("TRANDATE", descending=False) 

days_difference_subsquent_trans = df.with_columns(pl.col("TRANDATE").diff().over("ACQDISP").alias("date_diff_subsequent_trans"))

shape: (7, 5)
┌─────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ ACQDISP ┆ TRANDATE   ┆ SHARES_ADJ ┆ TPRICE_ADJ ┆ date_diff_subsequent_trans │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---                        │
│ str     ┆ date       ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ duration[ms]               │
╞═════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 2000.0     ┆ 6.7        ┆ null                       │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 6000.0     ┆ 6.45       ┆ 0ms                        │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 3000.0     ┆ 6.52       ┆ 0ms                        │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-09 ┆ 5.4e6      ┆ 60.75      ┆ null                       │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 2.1954e6   ┆ null       ┆ 15d                        │
│ D       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 4.63418e6  ┆ 52.435     ┆ 967d                       │
│ A       ┆ 2014-12-17 ┆ 3.84581e6  ┆ null       ┆ 3767d                      │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────┘

How do I calculate the distance between D and A or A and D?

I don't understand your question.  Say in row 5, which is a D.  Do you want the number of days since the last D, and the number of days since the last A?

yes, for example, D (2004-08-24) and A (2014-12-17) would work too. But I would also need D(2001-12-31) and A (2004-08-09) as well just to be clear

Yes, I'm just trying to restate the problem in a way you can solve it.  For every row, you want two additional columns:  days since the last A, and days since the last D.  Right?

I think that would solve majority of the problem

Can you show the exact final dataframe output you expect from this example?

@jqurious It looks to me like the answer you deleted solves the problem.  Why did you delete it?

@TimRoberts Thanks for the feedback. The question received multiple downvotes after my answer. This made me think that I was missing something obvious (that others were seeing), and I was no longer sure if I was answering the actual question correctly - so I removed it.

You can use shift() to compare against the previous row to find out if there is a value change.
Here we check if id changes and shift the index value forward when it does:
df = pl.DataFrame({"id": ["D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "A"]}).with_row_index()

df.with_columns(
    id_change = pl.col("id") != pl.col("id").shift(),
    previous_index =
        pl.when(pl.col("id") != pl.col("id").shift())
          .then(pl.col("index").shift())
)

shape: (7, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬───────────┬────────────────┐
│ index ┆ id  ┆ id_change ┆ previous_index │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---            │
│ u32   ┆ str ┆ bool      ┆ u32            │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════════╪════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ D   ┆ null      ┆ null           │
│ 1     ┆ D   ┆ false     ┆ null           │
│ 2     ┆ D   ┆ false     ┆ null           │
│ 3     ┆ A   ┆ true      ┆ 2              │ # D -> A
│ 4     ┆ A   ┆ false     ┆ null           │ 
│ 5     ┆ D   ┆ true      ┆ 4              │ # A -> D
│ 6     ┆ A   ┆ true      ┆ 5              │ # D -> A
└───────┴─────┴───────────┴────────────────┘

.forward_fill() can be used to fill in the gaps.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("index").shift().over("id")
      .alias("previous_same"),
    pl.when(pl.col("id") != pl.col("id").shift())
      .then(pl.col("index").shift())
      .forward_fill()
      .alias("previous_different") 
)

shape: (7, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ id  ┆ previous_same ┆ previous_different │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ u32   ┆ str ┆ u32           ┆ u32                │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ D   ┆ null          ┆ null               │
│ 1     ┆ D   ┆ 0             ┆ null               │
│ 2     ┆ D   ┆ 1             ┆ null               │
│ 3     ┆ A   ┆ null          ┆ 2                  │
│ 4     ┆ A   ┆ 3             ┆ 2                  │ # filled
│ 5     ┆ D   ┆ 2             ┆ 4                  │
│ 6     ┆ A   ┆ 4             ┆ 5                  │
└───────┴─────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┘

For your actual task, you want to bring TRANDATE forward and subtract it.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("TRANDATE").diff().over("ACQDISP").alias("same"),
    (
        pl.col("TRANDATE") 
        -
        pl.when(pl.col("ACQDISP") != pl.col("ACQDISP").shift())
          .then(pl.col("TRANDATE").shift())
          .forward_fill()
    )
    .alias("different")
)

shape: (7, 6)
┌─────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ ACQDISP ┆ TRANDATE   ┆ SHARES_ADJ ┆ TPRICE_ADJ ┆ same         ┆ different    │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ date       ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ duration[ms] ┆ duration[ms] │
╞═════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 2000.0     ┆ 6.7        ┆ null         ┆ null         │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 6000.0     ┆ 6.45       ┆ 0ms          ┆ null         │
│ D       ┆ 2001-12-31 ┆ 3000.0     ┆ 6.52       ┆ 0ms          ┆ null         │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-09 ┆ 5.4e6      ┆ 60.75      ┆ null         ┆ 952d         │
│ A       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 2.1954e6   ┆ null       ┆ 15d          ┆ 967d         │
│ D       ┆ 2004-08-24 ┆ 4.63418e6  ┆ 52.435     ┆ 967d         ┆ 0ms          │
│ A       ┆ 2014-12-17 ┆ 3.84581e6  ┆ null       ┆ 3767d        ┆ 3767d        │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘

